# get position of selected button in listview

Tags: android, button, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a list view every item in list contains textviews and button what I want is when I click on the button of any item in list I want to printout the position of button if i clicked the button in first line i want to print out 0 and go on but it doesn't work
    this is my method to display view

```
    private void displayListView() {

            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries();

            // The desired columns to be bound
            String[] columns = new String[] {
                    PhonesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
                    PhonesDbAdapter.KEY_CONTINENT,

            };

            // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
            int[] to = new int[] {
                    R.id.continent,
                    R.id.name

            };

            // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
            //as well as the layout information
            dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this, R.layout.phone_layout,
                    cursor,
                    columns,
                    to,
                    0);

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
    public void print(View v)
        {

        }


and here how my item look like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:background="#f0f0f0" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/continent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"

        android:textColor="#275a0d"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/call"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:onClick="print"/>

</RelativeLayout>

and this the layout that contain the listview
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#f0f0f0">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/myFilter" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10">
        </EditText>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

i spent alot of time with this problem and i hope that u can help me and im really sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you implementing the method `getView()` on your adapter?
That's where you want to add the `OnClickListener` to your `Button`

Once you do that you can set the position as the tag of the `Button` and retrieve it on the `onClick` method.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, parent, false);
        Button myButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id. call);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = (int)view.getTag();
                //Do whatever you want with the position here
            }
        });

        myButton.setTag(position);

        return row;
}
```

Comment: Same thing I also told but didn't write the code... Correct answer no doubt. He need to create custom adapter first.

Comment: Unfortunately, im not implementing the method getView

Comment: @user3871129 You need to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

From last 3 three years I am not working on android so I am not sure my suggestion is correct or not. You need to test it for you purpose.

In your above case you cannot use onItemClickListner because it can only be used when you are tracking your complete list row. What I think is you can create a custom adapter and override its getView method. In getView method you will have your position and you can set button click listner for you button in getview. So In this way you can get your button position.

You try it once if you need some code then I can try to write it for you...

THIS IS HOW YOU CAN CREATE CUSTOM ADAPTER.

```
public class my_custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context                     = null;
    ArrayList<String>  elements                 = null;

    public my_custom_adapter(Context context, int type, ArrayList<String>  elements)
    {
        super(context, type, elements);
        this.elements =  elements;
        this.context = context;
    }


    //THIS IS SIMPLY A CLASS VIEW WILL HOLD DIFFERENT VIEWS OF YOUR ROW.
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView tv;
        public Button cb;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
                                               Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // HERE I AM INFLATING LISTVIEW LAYOUT.
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_layout, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.cb = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            rowView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        if (holder != null) {

            holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // IF YOUR BUTTON TAG HERE AND YOU CAN HAVE POSITION USING "position" PARAMETER

            }
            });
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: CarlosJimenez already written that code you need to override array adapter or simpleadapter class and there you can override your getview method.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how can I do that

Comment: I have given you an example how to create custom adapter. you can use this adapter instead of "SimpleCursorAdapter".

Comment: now this line retrun list from my database List<Phone> phones = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries(); then i did this listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); but here i goy an error ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.phone_layout, phones );

Comment: If you don't know hot to implement a custom adapter, [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) you'll find a really nice tutorial about it